# Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL', not sure what to do, or how to download it with new firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

so i updated firebase to the new version by mistake and I keep getting this error, but i'm unsure what to do. I"m trying to download the profile image into a string... please help

```
objc func handleSignUp() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, email.count > 0 else { return }
    guard let username = usernameTextField.text, username.count > 0 else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text, password.count > 0 else { return }



    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            //print ("Registration SuccesS", user?.uid ?? "")

            guard let image = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image else {return}

            guard let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3) else { return }

            let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
            Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_Image").child(filename).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in

                if let err  = err {
                    print("Failed to upload:", err)
                    return
                }
               guard let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else { return }



print("Successfully uploaded profile image:",profileImageUrl)


                guard let uid = user?.user.uid else {return}

                //guard let uid = user.uid else {return}

                guard let fcmToken = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken else {return}

                let dictionaryValues = ["username": username, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl ,"fcmToken": fcmToken]
                let values = [uid: dictionaryValues ]

                Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Failed to save user info in Db", err)
                        return
                    }
                    print("Successfuly saved user info")

                    guard let mainTabBarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController else { return }             
                    mainTabBarController.setupViewControllers()  
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

Comment: don't download the photoURL for storage bcs it can change. Just pull it from `firebase.auth()` each time. Otherwise, you'll end up with some users having 404/notfound photoURL responses.

Comment: it's just the way my codebase is, it's already like set up that way.

Comment: it's all like intertwined and it's just better to have it like that, that's why i just need to figure out that specific part.

Comment: In the latest SDK you get the download URL from the storage reference. So in your case that'd be `Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_Image").child(filename).downloadURL { (url, error) in`. Also see the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_files) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448396/value-of-type-storagemetadata-has-no-member-downloadurl