# Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL' in swift and firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm currently watching a youtube video telling me how to make a social media app. But when I was writing the code, I encountered an error in this function. This is a very annoying error, so if you can, please help me

```
func setupUser(userUid: String) {
    if let imageData = self.userImgView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {
        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in

            let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

            let userData = [
                "username": self.usernameField.text!,
                "userImg": downloadURL!
                ] as [String : Any]

            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userUid).setValue(userData)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The error happened in this code...

```
 let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
```

There are other questions on Stackoverflow like this one, but I tried all of them but got an error. Can you please help me. Can you just edit my code a little bit to fix it? Please don't lead me straight to the documentation. I've tried that but it didn't work

Comment: I tried the code out, but  I got an error

Comment: What's wrong with the other questions?  Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448396/value-of-type-storagemetadata-has-no-member-downloadurl. Please edit the question to be very specific about why this problem is different than the others.

Comment: My code is different

Comment: Ok ill edit the question

Comment: Your code is not really much different than the others. It's the exact same problem.

Comment: Well, in the other ones, I don't see an improved version of let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

Comment: Read the answers carefully.  You need to update your pods and use a different API.

Comment: I did all that.

Comment: Apparently you didn't, because your code is still using the old API.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to match the documentation. See where your code is this `let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString` but it's supposed to be `riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in` followed by `guard let downloadURL = url`? Can you take a look at the documentation and give that a try? [Upload from Data In Memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory)

Comment: Ok ill check the docs

Comment: Also, the [StorageMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata.html#storagereference) class doesn't have a direct .downloadURL property so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for uploading content in firebase storage

```
typealias blockCompletedWith = (Bool, String) -> Void 

func uploadToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, path: String, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg" //Modify as per your need

    let store = Storage.storage()
    let storeRef = store.reference().child(path)
    let _ = storeRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let _ = metadata else {
            print("error occured: \(error.debugDescription)")
            blockCompletedWith(false, "")
            return
        }

        storeRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {
                blockCompletedWith(true, urlText)
            }
            else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

After getting the URL from this function you can do your further processing on data as per your need.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Happy to help!

Comment: I worked! But then I got an error in my code. I can fix that error but, I'll tell you if I have more problems

Comment: I do have a problem with my other codes, so I'm gonna edit the question and paste it.

Comment: Wait, is there a way to get an older version of firebase.

Comment: Ok, ill do that but is there a way I can get an older version of the podfile

Comment: Yes you can do that... pod “pod name”, ‘~> podVersion’ this is one way to do that

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score -1):

The correct thing to downgrade the podfile. In you podfile, type

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage', '4.4.0'
```

Then it will work. You don't have to downgrade other podfiles.

Comment: This is not the correct way...what if firebase deprecate this in near future then you have no choice but to upgrade. Rest is your choice.

Comment: Well, it's okay for now.

Comment: @WonixerA You're not going to want to do that as it will break at some point and will definitely have intermittent operation - and that's going to be miserable to track down in the future. You should just update your code to match the current API as shown in the docs and you'll be set.